# Create daily offer

Tags: php, function, random, product

So i'm trying to create a daily offer for my exam project - The idea is to extract information from my DB and make some kind of random function that calls out a random product each day, but for now i'm pretty much stuck nowhere.

Any great guides or solutions?

Comment: Are you looking for a process idea ? Or a code snippet (in which case you should show what you've already tried)

Comment: I'm not really sure what i'm looking for since i'm still kindda new in web dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could do it :

1. Create a SQL table which will store your daily product (two columns `id_product` and `date` should suffice) -- let's call it `daily_products`
2. Create a PHP script which will select the product id for today's date from `daily_products`

   - If there is none, do an SQL request on your `products` table which will return only one line with an `ORDER BY RAND()`, then store the product id and today's date in `daily_products`
   - If there is one, do nothing
3. Call this PHP script daily

   - Either with a `cronjob` which will execute every day, say at 00:01
   - Or on the first daily visit of your website (in this case, it should be called before your website rendering)